# Unable to tell if USB drive is correct

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I am attempting to install ubuntu desktop on a new PC with no other operating system on it.  I have followed the directions to place the install .iso on a USB drive, and the install menu comes up correctly.  However, when I select the Install option the computer just hangs with the install menu screen still up.  The same thing happens if I attempt to try out Ubuntu.  I found instructions for verifying the contents of the USB drive, but when I select that option, the computer hangs in the same way.  I found instructions for using F6 to change install options (like noapci, etc), but when I press F6, the screen flashes briefly to black (for less than a second) and then the install menu comes back up as if nothing happened.  The same thing happens if I try the Test Memory option.  I am able to use the very last menu option to get a boot: prompt to come up, but I'm not sure what to type there.  If I just press enter, the computer hangs also.  I was able to boot from this same USB drive to the network install (mini.iso) previously and got much further into the installation, but ran into DHCP problems I have not yet solved.

Comment: An update.  I tried using the [tab] key to edit the installation options and add nomodeset, noapci and apci=off to the line.  Those options appear to make no difference.  If I remove 'splash' from the line, however I can see that the screen is now absolutely full of periods (.) scrolling on and on forever.  I have left this go for ten minutes and nothing further happens.

Comment: You might want to check the downloaded ISO for errors https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM, also, some hardware specs would have been nice.

Comment: It appears that using the USB drive previously for the network install confused the program that tried to set it up for the full install.  I am now installing off a DVD made from the same .iso and I got a completely different-looking menu. (and it seems to be working as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a bootable USB with persistence enabled.

> A Live USB is configured to run on almost all desktops and has a **great
>   compatibility with various hardware**. If you want to test the Linux
>   distro on various computers, using a Live USB with data persistency is
>   the best way to do it.- https://www.maketecheasier.com/persistent-live-usb-vs-full-install-usb/

Comment: I did not get the impression that Gabriel wants "want to test the Linux distro on various computers". How is this answer relevant to the question???

Comment: I was pointing out that persistency would provide greater hardware support, if the ISO is error free

Comment: ...and what does one has to do with the other???

Comment: If it was a hardware problem that was causing the lockups, I could see that helping.  Turns out it was the program that created the bootable USB drive didn't work a second time on the same drive and produced a bad drive from a good image.  Perhaps if I had formatted the drive, but I had explorer windows I wanted to keep open, and that would have closed them.